# Two factor authentication on google compute engine VM breaks console SSH access

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to tighten up security on our Google Compute Engine VMs so I installed and configured libpam-google-authenticator to use Two Factor Authentication. Concisely I did:

```
<set up ssh public/private key>
sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
google-authenticator # follow steps & scan the code with Google Authenticator on your phone
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
    AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
/etc/pam.d/sshd
    # @include common-auth
    auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

This works fine using a client like PuTTY.

Specifically, the problem I have is when I try the HTML SSH button on the Google Compute Engine console page, here's a picture of the button:

[image: gce console ssh connect]

It never logs in, it just keeps retrying reporting:

> Transferring SSH keys to the VM.
>   The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update.

2FA must be stopping GCE from being able to transfer the ssh keys it generates, is there any way to enable it or is it incompatible with pam_google_authenticator?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 factor authentication (2 step verification) with Google compute engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450402/2-factor-authentication-2-step-verification-with-google-compute-engine)

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's not a duplicate unfortunately - 2FA works on GCE with PuTTY but not with the HTML SSH button GCE have, hopefully my edits to the question clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a duplicate - [2 factor authentication (2 step verification) with Google compute engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450402/2-factor-authentication-2-step-verification-with-google-compute-engine)

They seemed to have figured it out there, here is some I got from that post:

Apart of adding a line to /etc/pam.d/sshd, one should also comment out the @include common-auth line. So it should be something like:

```
auth       required     pam_google_authenticator.so # from the original instructions
# @include common-auth # commenting out is new...
```

Apart of changing the ChallengeResponseAuthentication property in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, one should also add AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive in the following line:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes # from the original instructions
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive # this is new...
```

Of course, this is on top of the regular instructions of installing libpam-google-authenticator, changing the sshd and sshd_config (as mentioned above), restarting the ssh/sshd service, and setting up the google-authenticator for the account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it's not exactly the problem I'm experiencing. I saw that post before and my problem isn't that it isn't working at all - it works fine using a client like PuTTY, it's just that it doesn't work when using GCP's SSH button (the image I included). I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: ok I understand, what I can see from the documentation for SSH from the Browser (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) it does seem like this is a tool GCP built and password authentication would be something that you would need to figure out how to enable, if at all possible. Its very likely that this is not possible.

Comment: Looking at this more I really dont think this is going to be possible, the SSH from the Browser function is a tool GCP has built in and I guess they have SSH keys added in as the default. I think your only solution would be to add some extra security on top of that SSH connection from GCP. Possibly via only restricting only that user to log in via SSH keys combined with a IP restriction or domain restriction for that user.

Comment: Good read about this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/aoO8L5CdbnE

Comment: Hey David, like a few of the contributors to that discussion I'm put off maintaining firewall rules for ever-changing IP addresses! We all log on remotely and no-one has fixed IP, and there's often travel involved. The 2FA seemed like a handy, not-too-much-extra authentication step - but I do suspect you're right, it's probably not possible.

Comment: I personally use Two Factor on all my servers and only allow ssh login for specific users, then if I have a customer who really wants to use ssh keys I allow only that customer user to login to ssh via ssh keys. I was thinking what you could do was only allow the GCP user who logs in to your server via the SSH from the Browser tool to be able to log in via SSH keys, then you make sure that user has no rights and has to su to another user to actually do anything.

Comment: I also noticed on the issue that they suggested using GCP`s Internal Network (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/private-google-access/private-google-access) - that is what I do for my provider, I only allow my servers to access each over over the internal network.

Comment: Cheers David, both good suggestions, I do the same requiring them to su but I hadn't heard of the Internal Network before, will check it out

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the following error:

> The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update.

It is possible that the instance have outdated VM guest environment.
 Check out [this documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#guest-overview) for more information. Also, there is an [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/67997017) for the mentioned error, there are some suggestions which may work for you.

Edit:  In addition, 2-FA on GCE VM is a customized SSH configuration using Google Authenticator. SSH in Browser and SSH via gcloud functionality may fail as Google Authenticator is not the same mechanism as the key-based SSH mechanisms configured by SSH in browser or gcloud SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the VM guest environment is fine, if I turn off 2-factor auth it works again (i.e. with no change to VM guest environment)

Comment: I looked more into this. Here is additional info: 2-FA on GCE VM is a customized SSH configuration using Google Authenticator. SSH in Browser and SSH via gcloud functionality may fail as Google Authenticator is not the same mechanism as the key-based SSH mechanisms configured by SSH in browser or gcloud SSH.

Comment: That sounds promising, do you have the source of that info please? Thanks

Comment: @JohnLeonard, It seems there is no public documentation available explaining with more details, however can refer to this documentation on [SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) and for google authenticator [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35157/how-does-google-authenticator-work) and [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) for more insight.